# I cannot connect to a sites socket

Tags: node.js, web-scraping, socket.io

I've been trying to do this but can you connect to another websites their socket.io server? I've been trying to scrape data from a website that uses socket.io for live updates. It would be very handy if this were to be possible.

I'm trying to get live updates from the website https://www.ethercrash.io/ - However I tried the following code and wouldn't get any updates other than a connection;

```
var io = require('socket.io-client');
var socket = io('https://www.ethercrash.io')

socket.on('connect', function(){
  console.log(true);
});

socket.on('msg', function(data) {
  console.log('chat message');
});

socket.on('disconnect', function(){
  console.log(false);
});
```

Am I doing something wrong or is this just not possible?

Comment: Add `socket.on('error', err => console.log(err)).on('connect_error', err => console.log(err));` and see if it tells you anything.  You will need a client version of socket.io that is compatible with whatever version of socket.io the server you're trying to connect uses.  There are no explicit limitations in socket.io that would prevent your server from connecting to some other socket.io server.

Comment: @jfriend00 sadly it doesn't log anything, it does log `true` as if it connects, it is very odd.

Comment: OK, it does connect - you didn't say that in the question.  Then, that probably means you have to do something else in order to get it to send information.  You will have to use the debugger on the regular web page to see what the regular web page is sending to the server, either over the socket.io connection or via an Ajax call.  I looked at the webpage https://www.ethercrash.io/ in the debugger and it doesn't create a socket.io connection so I can't debug it for you. We need more information about exactly what information you're trying to get?

Comment: FYI, on the URL https://www.ethercrash.io/play, I can see two socket.io connections and lots of data flowing on one of them.  I see `player_bet`, then `player_bet`, then `game_started` with alot of data, then `game_tick` and so on...

Comment: @jfriend00 I'm trying to pull the `msg` event to pull the live chat messages. I do know there's two different socket connections, but at the one I am using I looked at the messages on ethercrash.io/play and there when I click on messages in the debugger it shows all the data I need, however when I'm performing this on my local server there's no incoming data.

Comment: Then, look at all the other ajax calls going on to see if that's relevant to starting the data flow.  Or, do there need to be certain cookies present?  You may have to simulate more of what the web page does to get the data flowing.

Comment: @jfriend00 I figured you wouldn't need any additional data to get it flowing (the chatbox) as you can view the chatbox without being logged-in. I'll have another look however.

Edit: list of cookies associated with the socket.io that pulls chat messages http://prntscr.com/qhlmh0

Comment: I see this being sent over socket.io `["join",["english"]]` early in the connection process.  I don't know if that's the result of `socket.emit("join", "english")` or `socket.emit("join", ["english"]);`, but both are worth trying.

Comment: @jfriend00 I must say that's actually a smart one, sadly I tried both options and n'either worked, but the chat does indeed work with channels you need to join. I looked into the code of the website and this is indeed what they do when the connection is made they emit http://prntscr.com/qhm9jk - I also tried listening to the `bets` event that should be fired when a player on the website places a bet (its part of the game), however that isn't being fired either.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/205096/discussion-between-martijn-ebbens-and-jfriend00).

Answer (score 0):

I use the following in all my node.js / express / socket.io projects.  Hopefully it helps you out.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/2.2.0/socket.io.js"></script>

        <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {

            // NOTE, I AM FORCING WEBSOCKET TRANSPORT HERE.  AND AM NOT ALLOWING 
            // SOCKET.IO TO FALL BACK TO LONG POLLING FALLBACK, 
            // SO YOU CAN REMOVE THE TRANSPORTS AND GO WITH SOCKET.IO DEFAULTS
            // PORT I'M USING IS 3000 -- SO THE PORT CAN BE IMPORTANT, DEPENDING ON YOUR USASGE 

            var socket = io.connect("https://MY-SERVER-NAME-HERE.eastus.cloudapp.azure.com:3000", {
              secure: true,
              transports: ["websocket"],
              path: "/socket/socket.io"
            });

            // EVERY TIME THE NODE.JS SERVER SENDS US 'MESSAGE' WE'LL DISPLAY THAT UPDATED NUMBER IN A DIV
            socket.on("message", function(msg) {
                document.getElementById("message").innerHTML = msg;
            });
    });
    </script>
    </head>

        <body style="width: 100%;">
          <div id="message" style="text-align: center; width: 100%; font-size: 2em;"></div>
        </body>
</html>
```

You also are depending on that 'other site' (running the socket server) emitting out to either ALL connected clients or to your connection specifically.   Unless either of those happen, you will only have a connection with no messages being emitted out (to be read / parsed).

Sockets are really fun to work with and full of potential once you get the hang of it!

Comment: Even though this is clientside and not serverside I will give it a try.

Comment: @MartijnEbbens -- Another note:  in all my use cases, I have a server side node.js process running, but the clients that are connected to the socket are all web browser based.  I've never had another server-side process connected as a client.

Comment: Note that I'm trying to connect to a server that is *not* owned or operated by me.

Comment: I made the connection on the clientside right now, but there's still not what I'm hoping to get, see left my output, and right the websites output I'm trying to scrape; http://prntscr.com/qhcvx2

Comment: I see, you ARE connecting to the socket (I can see the SID, etc. all being received on the left -- can you expand that and let me see the rest of what that object contains?)   But on the right, I can see the actual data messages being emitted.  That's what you're missing.  In my experience, a sites' use of sockets like this will be limited to authorized users (by token or key)... so they can be sure you have an 'account' and can be authenticated.  That's probably what you're running into.  Unless they have an API that allows you to make sa socket connection?

Comment: if you are not authenticated on the site you can still view the chatbox (messages etc.).
http://prntscr.com/qhd0fb

It's just weird, might this have to do with them not maybe allowing other origins to listen to their sockets (if that's a thing)? If that's the case, how else could I scrape the website that requires live updates.

Comment: Yep, that's probably it.  I know if I ran their site I would limit socket connections to only MY apps (the chat element is a web component of theirs, that is allowed access for example).  Otherwise you run the risk of having rogue people like us (LOL) experimenting and causing performance or other issues.  You're right, the next approach I would try would be scraping (note: not necessarily legal to do, so do so at your own risk)...  but if you'd like to use Node.js, you should check out puppeteer -- it's what I use for similar needs.  and I make my OWN API that 'feeds' me data!

Comment: Also, where the chat is is the page https://www.ethercrash.io/play, when I go to the main page on that site it doesn't show any socket connections when I'm logged out.

Comment: Well, if that's the case - do you have any better ideas of scraping the sites chatbox for example, to get live updates from the chat?

Comment: puppeteer.   I'd use puppeteer and try to have it WATCH the chat and whenever the DOM is updated with a new message, have that trigger some event.  OR maybe pipe the chat content to a file and use another NPM package, like chokidar, to watch for file change and then cause the triggering of an event to do whatever you want.

Comment: I've been trying to do this with puppeteer as well, it makes things a lot more complicated then just listening to the socket, but I got stuck on checking for updates within the chatbox. I mean surely comparing the entire chatbox each time versus the previous chatbox isn't the fastest.

Comment: Agreed, it's tricky... first thing that comes to mind is saving a local copy and doing a 'compare' at some interval, but that doesn't seem efficient at all.  best of luck, we better end this thread, feel free to take it to chat if I can help or you need to kick around ideas further.